# FAB 40 Install issues

Tags: 2007, stsadm

I am trying to install one of the FAB 40 templates for MOSS and I am having some trouble with it.  I have run my script to install which is:

```
stsadm -o addsolution -filename ApplicationTemplateCore.wsp

stsadm -o deploysolution -name ApplicationTemplateCore.wsp -allowgacdeployment -immediate

stsadm -o copyappbincontent

pause

stsadm -o addsolution -filename BudgetingTrackingMultipleProjects.wsp

stsadm -o deploysolution -name BudgetingTrackingMultipleProjects.wsp -allowgacdeployment -immediate

pause
```

From the documentation I have seen I seem to be doing the deployment right.  I am wondering if I am missing any Central Admin features, however the ApplicationTemplateCore.wsp file I though was supposed to take care of that.  It installs fine, but when I try to make a site off of the new template i get this error

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040E07   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.UpdateField(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrXML) 
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.UpdateField(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrXML)

Anyone who works with SharePoint knows the wonderfully detailed errors they give **(extreem sarcasm used)**  Any help on this issue would be great Thanks.

Comment: Off topic for this site.  You'll get a better response on [sharepoint.se]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured it out (at least for it to work for me).  I am still unsure if I am missing anything to keep me from being able to create the site directly through the SharePoint front end.  What I had to do was create the site through the stsadm command line.

```
stsadm.exe -o createsite
        -url <url>
        -owneremail <someone@example.com>
        [-ownerlogin <DOMAIN\name>]
        [-ownername <display name>]
        [-secondaryemail <someone@example.com>]
        [-secondarylogin <DOMAIN\name>]
        [-secondaryname <display name>]
        [-lcid <language>]
        [-sitetemplate <site template>]
        [-title <site title>]
        [-description <site description>]
        [-hostheaderwebapplicationurl <web application url>]
        [-quota <quota template>]
```

Some of these parameters are required for instance the URL, owneremail, and ownerlogin are required.  The ownerlogin is not required if your environment has an active directory that is linked to the owneremail to automatically provide permissions.  Here is the script I wrote to get this to work.  Notice for the sitetemplate command, I am using the template code of PROJMULTI#0 instead of the name of the template.

```
C:\stsadm -o createsite -url http://whereyouwantyoursite -owneremail validemailaddress -lcid 1033 -sitetemplate PROJMULTI#0 -ownerlogin domain\username
```

then, hopefully you will get this message...

Operation completed successfully.